# Firebase Test Lab - I can't use ScreenShotter with UIAutomator, as I have no Activity

Tags: screenshot, android-uiautomator, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to use the ScreenShotter feature in Test Labs, on Firebase within my UIAutomator tests.

However, instead of just needing a context, it needs an Activity, and I can't get or don't have one from within a UIAutomator test.

<s>Am I screwed</s> Does this only work with Espresso?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` and use Espresso and UiAutomator if you need.

```
public class SampleActivityTests extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SampleActivity> {

    private UiDevice mDevice;

    public SampleActivityTests() {
        super(SampleActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        getActivity();
        mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    }

    public void testAddNote() throws InterruptedException {
        // Take a screenshot when app becomes visible.
        onView(isRoot());
        ScreenShotter.takeScreenshot("sample 1", getActivity());
        mDevice.pressDPadLeft();
        mDevice.pressDPadLeft();
        ScreenShotter.takeScreenshot("sample 2", getActivity());
    }
}
```

Comment: The code worked, compiled and ran, and it took my 2 screenshots, however they were empty/black screens. At no stage in the test video were the screens black, so I'm thinking maybe it was the gaming library I'm using. I use an `AndroidLauncher` from here [AndroidLauncher](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/9b8f20b2d0e96e53f0f2b98dc8f6131c810aae71/extensions/gdx-setup/src/com/badlogic/gdx/setup/resources/android/src/AndroidLauncher) which extends Activity, so I assumed that would work, but I guess not